# .htaccess file doesn't seem to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I'm running WAMP server 2.1
I decide to bite the bullet and play with the .htaccess file. I created one in the root dir c:\wamp\www and is thus:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 405 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 408 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 502 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
ErrorDocument 504 http://localhost:8070/Test/error-page.php
```

I wanted to set a default error doc and use some php to redirect.

Because of a conflict of port 80, I use 8080, so

```
http://localhost/ becomes http://localhost:8080/
```

Navigating to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

works, and navigating to a dummy directory produces the familiar 404 error and does not redirect to error-page.php

I have set

```
AllowOverride All
```

except for

```
<Directory "cgi-bin">
...
</Directory>
```

the .htaccess file was created in notepad and is an ansi file, and NO it is called .htaccess NOT .htaccess.txt or other variation.

I have set

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Please help, why doesn't it work ?

Comment: If you add a bunch of gibberish (like `asdjadkjslfdae`) in your htaccess file, do you get a 500 internal server error when you try to visit something like `/`?

Comment: @Jon Lin
This morning when I started the computer, got a 404 error for **localhost:8080**, so something has happened, then tried your suggestion, still the same - 404, so not too sure whats happened here, any suggestions would be appreciated. I will also try resetting **httpd.conf**.
Note I did reset my computer yesterday when mucking about, so don't understand what the difference between yesterday and today is.

Comment: Well, if you put bad config data in your htaccess and it isn't throwing a 500 error, your htaccess file isn't being accessed.

Answer (score 2):

fixed the problem, what was happening, httpd.conf was trying to load a non-existent module, and therefore, the conf file wasn't being loaded, I did look in the logs before, but didn't notice this. thanks for your help !!

Comment: Your question helped me. My problem was that my **.htaccess** was **.htaccess.txt**.